# java project and external file fil.properties

Tags: java, properties, load, external

I'm trying to load a external file.properties when I launch my java program but this does not load the file.
i have this program and the file.properties in my desktop.
this is no web application.

I have also configured the environment variables on the pc as classpath and path but when i run the program it don't sees them

```
String filePath = "file.properties";
Properties data = new Properties();
    try{

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        data.load(stream);
        execute(args,data);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

this is the error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.properties (Impossibile
>   trovare il file specificato.) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:137)
>     at
>   it.applications.AssCitRice.ParseXmlSct.(ParseXmlSct.java:42)
>     at
>   it.applications.AssCitRice.ParseXmlSct.main(ParseXmlSct.java:286)
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (it..applications.AssegniCitRicezionePresentazione.ParseXmlSct).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Help me please

Comment: `FileNotFoundException`. Please check the filePath, it seems like it is not correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct.. .:(

Comment: I assume ParseXmlSct is your class name? What is line 42 in that file?

Comment: yes ParseXmlSct  is my class name

Comment: And what is on line 42 in that class file?

Comment: But, please check the filepath once again and that the file actually exists. You are getting an exception because java cannot find your file.

Comment: FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

Comment: Well, as I stated ealier. Your file does either not exist or you are using the wrong path. The path could look something like this `"C:/path/to/file/file.properties"`

Answer (score 0):

You had to use a correct (full) pathname such as:

```
String filePath = APLHOME + File.separator + "file.properties";
or
String filePath = System.getenv("APLHOME") + File.separator + "file.properties";
```

There is no mechanism in opening text files to look in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` basically just means that either your file does not exists or you have provided the wrong path.

You need to provide the absolute path. Otherwise Java will not be able to find it.

```
//The below will work great as long as the file exists in that path.
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/test.txt"));

//This will however not work
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("/test.txt"));
```